# Java program to print first nonrepeating character in a string

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "XXYZZA";

        char[] a = str.toCharArray();
        int count=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
        {
            if (a[i] == a[i++]) 
            {
                count++;

            } 
            else
                System.out.println(a[i++]);

        }

    }
```

the print statement in the "else" part is not being executed. 
the desired output should be

```
Y
A
```

Comment: change to `if (a[i] == a[i + 1]) ` but be careful about the OOB Exception waiting to happen

Comment: There's a difference between `i++` and `++i`, this will help you with the answer.

Comment: You might want to take this input `XYZXZA`. It should still o/p `Y A`.

Comment: @Sid yes and no since it will increment twice per loop.

Comment: @ScaryWombat changing it worked and I removed the else statement and moved the print inside the if clause and changed the condition to if(a[i] != a[i+1]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first and for-most, proper indentations please, helps out a lot to understand the code.

Secondly, `if (a[i] == a[i++])` is not the right way to go because of 2 reasons

1. your for loop will start skipping ***i*** values since you are using a **unary operator**, which will act **directly on the operand**.
2. **ArrayIndexOutOfBounds** : once your i reaches its max value of `a.length - 1` your test condition `i++` will try to access the element at **index** `a.length`, which, as you might have guessed it, does not exist.

What you need is some sort of **sorting algorithm** without actually saving the sorted sequence.

Comment: that condition would have been so elegant with a `while` loop though!

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will ensure proper indentations on next post.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, may help you

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "XXYZZA";

    char[] a = str.toCharArray();
    HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add( a[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
    {
      if (!set.contains(a[i]) && (i+1 == a.length || a[i] != a[i+1]))
      {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
      }
      set.add(a[i]);

    }
```

Comment: why are you casting `chars` to `ints` ?

Comment: Your code does not work for string "aabffyggy" - it is showing **b**
and **y** which is not the right answer